# How to define onPressed property for button

Tags: flutter

What is the difference for these two variants? If the function **_getCsvDocunent** is just void type then what does it mean if we define onPressed like `onPressed: () => _getCsvDocunent(),` ?

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Provide .csv data file'),
    onPressed: _getCsvDocunent,
),
```

vs

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Provide .csv data file'),
    onPressed: () => _getCsvDocunent(),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In `onPressed:_getCsvDocunent`: `onPressed` gets an reference to `_getCsvDocument` passed to it. This way of passing a reference is only possible when the function to be passed is **already defined** and is **compatible** with `onPressed`.
- In `onPressed: () => _getCsvDocunent()`: `onPressed` gets the value returned by
  `_getCsvDocunent` after it is done executing.
- In `onPressed: () => _getCsvDocunent()`: `onPressed` gets a reference to `_getCsvDocument` exactly similar to the case in the first bullet point, difference being, in this case a function reference (`_getCsvDocument`) is **directly passed** to `onPressed` instead of using an inline function to return a reference to `_getCsvDocument`.